# Employee Evaluation Scoring Form

Tags: datagridview

I have an Employee Evaluation Program (C# WinForm) in which managers should see their employees and score them based on some criteria. A simplified database diagram showed in Figure1.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfb5E.jpg)

Tables Definitions:
Prs: Personnel (Employees)
Job: Job of personnel
Post: A Joining table for Prs and Job (since they have many-to-many relationship)
SubCrt: Criteria for evaluating employees
Scoring: Table in which employees’ scores should be saved

Necessary Descriptions:
-   Evaluation takes place every 3 months (called a Season)
-   Criteria for every job is different from others
-   Every employee may have more than one post in a season (because of job change). So we have to handle its results

And WinForm showed in Figure 2.

Scenario:
-   Manager selects a job
-   ***DataGridView*** will be **filled** based on **selected job** of ComboBox like showed in Figure 3.

- Now manager can type every employees’ scores related to every criteria

My major problem is how to implement such a table in ***DataGridView*** that can be used for ***data entry*** (inserting, updating, deleting scores)?

Your extra ideas and suggestions about DB, it’s relationships, C# Form and … will be kindly appreciated.
Regards

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Scoring_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        public int rows(int JobId)
        {
            var row = from crt in db.SubCrts
                      join job in db.Jobs
                      on crt.JobId equals job.JobId
                      where job.JobId == JobId
                      select crt.JobId;
            return row.Count();

        }
        public int columns(int JobId)
        {
            var Col = from prs in db.Prs
                      join post in db.Posts
                      on prs.PrsId equals post.PrsId
                      join job in db.Jobs
                      on post.JobId equals job.JobId
                      where job.JobId == JobId
                      select prs.PrsId;
            return Col.Count();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = db.Jobs.ToList();
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "JobTitle";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "JobId";

            //===================================================
            string[] PrsID = new string[columns(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) - 1];
            string[] PrsName = new string[columns(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) - 1];
            string[] CrtID = new string[rows(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) - 1];
            string[] CrtName = new string[rows(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) - 1];
            string[,] tbl = new string[rows(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue))+2,
                                       columns(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue))+2];

            for (int i = 0; i < columns(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) - 1; i++)
            {
                var a = from prs in db.Prs
                        join post in db.Posts
                        on prs.PrsId equals post.PrsId
                        join job in db.Jobs
                        on post.JobId equals job.JobId
                        select prs.PrsId;
                PrsID[i] = a.ElementAt(i).ToString();
                var b = from prs in db.Prs
                        select (prs.FName + ' ' + prs.LName).ToString();
                PrsName[i] = b.ElementAt(i);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < rows(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) - 1; j++)
            {
                var c = from crt in db.SubCrts
                        join job in db.Jobs
                        on crt.JobId equals job.JobId
                        select crt.SubCId;
                CrtID[j] = c.ElementAt(j).ToString();
                var d = from crt in db.SubCrts
                        select crt.Title;
                CrtName[j] = d.ElementAt(j);
            }
            tbl[0, 0] = ""; tbl[0, 1] = ""; tbl[1, 0] = ""; tbl[1, 1] = "";
            for (int l = 2; l < columns(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) + 1; l++)
            {
                for (int m = 2; m < rows(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)) + 1; m++)
                {
                    tbl[0, l] = PrsID.ElementAt(l - 2);
                    tbl[1, l] = PrsName.ElementAt(l - 2);
                    tbl[m, 0] = CrtID.ElementAt(m - 2);
                    tbl[m, 1] = CrtName.ElementAt(m - 2);

                    var h = from sss in db.Scorings
                            where sss.PrsId == Convert.ToInt32(tbl[0, l])
                            where sss.SubCId == Convert.ToInt32(tbl[m, 0])
                            select sss.Score;
                    tbl[l, m] = h.ElementAt(0).ToString();

                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;
        }
    }
}
```

After doing some search, I found a peace of code from Rob Sedgwick to convert a 1D array to a datatable

```
        public DataTable ConvertArrayToDatatable(MarketUnit[] arrList)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        if (arrList.Count() > 0)
        {
            Type arrype = arrList[0].GetType();
            dt = new DataTable(arrype.Name);

            foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in arrype.GetProperties())
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(propInfo.Name));
            }

            foreach (object obj in arrList)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    dr[dc.ColumnName] = obj.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ColumnName).GetValue(obj, null);
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
        }


        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return dt;
    }

}
```

**Would it be possible to change it to be used for my 2D array(Tbl)?**

Comment: It sounds like you have this under control. Have tried anything? Your question is very broad, and shows little effort.  Try something and post back if it does not work. You may want to read the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section to see how SO works and  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may want to tag you question with C# if that is what you are using.

Comment: Ommm... I do not know how to fill a DataGridView from different tables? And more importantly, it should insert,update and delete in the Scoring table.

Comment: Your question is very broad in scope because there is little information about what kind of problem you are having other than “I want to do this”. It is not clear what you have and what have you tried. From the picture you posted it appears you have a database, but I do not know. I am just guessing from the picture. It also appears you have at least started a form and a possible layout for that form below that. There is not enough information to say “Oh… just do this and that and there you go…” there are many things involved in what your post describes.

Comment: Identify your database and google how to read from that database into a DataTabe/DataSet/List/ or whatever you want to read it into. Since you are using a `DataGridView` a hint would be that the `DataGridView` plays nicely with Data Sets/Tables and can make what you describe relatively easy and convenient for add/update/delete. Your last comment is exactly what you should do… try to read the database into a data table and use that data table as a data source for the grid. Google is your friend here and should return many results for this.

Comment: Try something and if you cannot get it working update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you dear JohnG. OK,I'll try and update my question.  Regards

Comment: Here is what I did. Please help me cause the grid view doesn't show anything!

Comment: Do you see the picture I've attached?

Comment: I see the code you attached and am not exactly sure what is going on. Where is the `DataClasses1DataContext` class?

Comment: This is the LINQ instance of DB. I've used LINQ tech to connect app with the database. I think it's necessary to take a look at the picture containing DB digram, winform and the table to be shown in DataGridView that is actually the goal.

Comment: Hmm. Ok you have a LINQ instance of the DB. Therefore, it contains the database. The main problem you are going to have is that the code is making a two dimensional “String” array with `string[,] tbl` then the code uses this 2 dimensional “String” array as a data source for the `DataGridView` named  `dataGridView1` with the line `dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;`… this will not work as you expect. Granted it is an array of “Strings” but it will not display these strings properly. Most likely, it will display the LENGTH of each sting, not the string itself.

Comment: As I mention earlier, you will need either a List of <YourClass> or a DataTable to use as a data source. The string array will not work! Since I am unfamiliar with this context, instead of making a 2 dimensional string array… make a `DataTable` and fill it with you data. Alternatively, you can make a `Class` of the data you want and read the data into a `List` made up of this Class like List<MyClass>. You will be able use either one of the items as a data source and it will display properly. You may want to check to see what properties are available in the `db` variable, like `db.ToList();`

Comment: Thanks a thousand. You couldn't tell that better! As you mentioned, when I tested another similar code, the DataGridView showed "Lenght" instead of strings. By the way, cause I'm an infant in coding, I have to study and learn how to do your expert and fabulous peaces of advise. Again thank you very much dear JohnG. I'll take it further and inform you.

Comment: Would it be possible to change "Rob Sedgwick" code to convert **2D** arrays to dataTable?

Comment: I would take a closer look at the variable `db`. The line `DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();` is obviously returning a `DataTable` or a `DataSet`. It appears to be a `DataSet` from the line: `comboBox1.DataSource = db.Jobs.ToList();` here `db.Jobs` appears to already be a `DatatTable` but the code converts this table to a list. You should be able to convert just about any array to a table/list, however I am guessing this may be unnecessary depending on what Table(s) are returned to the variable `db`.

Comment: Take a close look at what table(s) are returned to `db` and you may not have to convert anything. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you very much dear JohnG, but would you please guide me a bit more? Your point is very interesting, and you have explained greatly. But still I'm none the wiser. How can I find out what does db return? And more importantly, my goal is to have something like array tbl[,] which can be seen and edit by user and as you know tbl[,] is a result of some joins from three or more DB tables. Again thanks and sorry cause I'm new to C# and almost know nothing.

Comment: According to the “Scenario” “Manager selects a job” from the combo box… what job? What "jobs" would be in this combo box’s list? Then the comment… _DataGridView will be filled based on selected job of ComboBox like showed in Figure 3._ Figure 3 shows columns of names and rows of skills? How is the selected “Job” related to this figure 3? Example if the “Job” was “secretary” what would figure 3 look like? I am confused as to WHAT the combo box contains and what you want the `DataGridView` to display depending on what “Job” is selected.

Comment: May I send you some info via E-mail?

Comment: Every unit (not mentioned in this question) has a manager and every manager has some employees. These employees' jobs are different and every job's criteria are different too. So, Figure3 is a table which has name of employees at the above (like column header), criteria (like the title of every row) and at the junction of those rows and columns is a score (which should bind to Scoring tbl) of that particular criteria for that person... Whole persons and criteria are related to selected job (the combo selected value) and list of jobs is Title column from Job table (please sea the DB diagram).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comments… your question is very broad in scope. There are many ways to achieve the goal of creating this “Employee Evaluation” form. So I hope this answer may help at least in the construction and managing a `DataTable` used as a `DataSource` to a `DataGridView`. My answer demonstrates how to filter a `DataTable` so the `DataGridView`  will display only the items that meet the filtered criteria or filtered on multiple criteria… i.e.. Filter a `Manager`’s selections to job types. Be aware this is about as basic as it gets and uses the `RowFilter` property of the `DataTable` to achieve this filtering. This `RowFilter` is somewhat limited and if the data is de-coupled from the original database the CRUD functions may become your problem. So use this as an example only.

The code you posted appears to be making this much more difficult than it has to be. The `DataSource` for ALL the `DataGridViews` and `ComboBoxes` in the example below are `DATATABLES`!. The posted codes insistence to convert the data source to a string array is unnecessary.

I used a different approach than what the database pictures shows. There are four (4) `DataTables`: `employeesDT`, is used as data source to the `DataGridView` `dgvEmployees`; `jobsCBDT` data table is used as a data source to the `ComboBox` `cbJobs`; `managersCBDT` is used as a data source to the `ComboBox` `cbManagers`;  and `evaluationsDT` is used as a data source to the `DataGridView` `dgvEvaluations`.

My approach broke this down to three main “Object”s: an “Employee” object, which may be a manager. This “Employee” object has an extra Boolean property to indicate if the employee is a manager; a “Job” object that defines the different “Job” types; finally the “Evaluation” object. This “Evaluation” class would have the following properties. You can do this without using classes but I would recommend you consider how useful they can be. The `DataTable` is necessary though.

```
public class Evaluation {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public Employee EmployeeEvaluated { get; set; }
  public Employee EvaluatingManager { get; set; }
  public Job JobEvaluated { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
  public double PersonalScore { get; set; }
  public double ImpactScore { get; set; }
  public double CommunicationScore { get; set; }
  public double DecisionMakingScore { get; set; }
  public double KnowledgeSkillsScore { get; set; }
  public double CareerDevelopmentScore { get; set; }
  public double InterpersonalScore { get; set; }
  public Evaluation() { }
}
```

Below is a `DataTable` definition for this `Evaluation` class.

```
public static DataTable GetEvaluationsDTStructure() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable("Evaluations");
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Employee Evaluated", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Evaluating Manager", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Job Title", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Start Date", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("End Date", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("Personal Score", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("Impact Score", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("Communication Score", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("Decision Making Score", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("Knowledge Skills Score", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("Career Development Score", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("Interpersonal Score", typeof(double));
  return dt;
}
```

This “Evaluation” structure appears to be missing from the post. This is an evaluation and an employee could have more than one evaluation. Figure 3 in the posted picture appears to be backwards. I am guessing here… I would think that there would be many evaluations and some evaluations from the same employee. The picture has this set up as columns. The rows on the other hand appear to be static. Using this strategy, there would be a column for every evaluation and there could be many. I switched this such that the columns are the scores for each area and the rows are the employee “evaluations”. I hope I am not missing something here like there are different scoring criteria depending on the selected job type.

[image]

Above is the form from the code below. You may have to adjust the tables to fit your needs. The top `DataGridView` `dgvEmployees` shows all the employees.  The buttons on the right will filter this list to “Managers Only”, “All Employees” and a button to “Save” this data to a file. Here you would update your database if needed.

Below that is the `DataGridView` `dgvEvaluations` that holds all the current evaluations. If there are many evaluations, you may want to filter the rows or search for a particular employee, manager or job. This is what the combo boxes do below the datagridview. There is an extra blank item added in the combo boxes to clear any filter or the user can click the “Clear Filter” button. Here you can filter the evaluations by a selected employee and by evaluating manager and job.

You can make changes to the current items and add new evaluations. Lastly, a button is on the right to save any changes. Again, I am simply writing the data table to a file. You would update your database.

NOTE Adding New Evaluations.

When users are allowed to input data, it is imperative that you check for valid data. Example, the `DataTable` columns for the scores are set as a type of `double`. If the user types in characters, the code will crash unless you address this issue. The same would apply to the date columns. To address this in a simple way (not the best) , the `DataError` event is wired up to capture when this happens, then simply display a message to the user that the input is invalid and cancel any changes in the grid. This prevents bad input from the users when typing in scores or dates.

The other user input problem is when the user types in the employee names for a new evaluation. If the user does not type the name exactly, then there will be problems later. If there is a new employee then that employee needs to be added to the employee’s database first. Same thing would apply to the “Job Title”, if the user types something that in not an existing job, then you will have errors later. Since these are employees and jobs… perhaps, a ComboBox cell here may make this easier for the user to simply select the employee and also the evaluating manager and job. This way, you can avoid the user typing incorrect info. You can look up `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` for these “employee” columns. There is commented code at the end of this post for this combo box cell. For cells with dates there is a good article on how to make a `DateTimePicker` column that works well, is user friendly and almost guarantees the user enters a valid date. [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx)

With that said, there are many problems with the code below, example, if you add a new employee into the top grid and then save the data… the combo boxes below will NOT be updated. This is something you will have to address. Another consideration is what to do if the user wants to add a new evaluation. Using the `DataGridView` to allow the user to do this is fine and doable, however you must implement several events and checks THROUGH the `DataGridView`. IMHO it may be easier to simply add a button to “add” a new evaluation and use this button to open an Evaluation form where the user could add the scores, change the employee etc… then save the evaluation. This may make things easier and would be user friendly.

I hope this helps, if I am totally missing something… please let me know and I will remove the answer. Good Luck

DataTable Definitions – evaluationsDT defined above

`jobsCBDT`

```
private static DataTable GetJobsDTStruc() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Job Title", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Job Description", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}
```

`employeeDT` managers dataTable is the same structure

```
private static DataTable GetEmplyeeDTSructure() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  dc = new DataColumn("Manager", typeof(bool));
  dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  dc = new DataColumn("First Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  dc = new DataColumn("Last Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  dt.Columns.Add("Job Title", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Full Name", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}
```

Main form methods

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  DataTable employeesDT;
  DataTable evaluationsDT;
  DataTable managersCBDT;
  DataTable jobsCBDT;
  DataTable employeesCBDT;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DisableComboEvents();                        // <-- turn off events while loading
    SetDataTables();                             // <-- get all the data tables
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employeesDT;
    dgvEvaluations.DataSource = evaluationsDT;
    employeesCBDT = employeesDT.Copy();          // <-- copy of data - you could use the same source though
    SetEmployeeDGVColumns();                     // <-- Style the columns for the employee datagridview
    SetEvaluationsDGVColumns();                  // <-- Style the columns for the evaluations datagridview
    SetEmployeeComboBox();                       // <-- set up the employee combo box for filtering
    SetManagerComboBox();                        // <-- set up the managers combo box for filtering
    SetJobsComboBox();                           // <-- set up the jobs combo box for filtering
    labelEmployeeList.Text = "All Employees";
    EnableComboEvents();                         // <-- turn events back on

  }

  private void DisableComboEvents() {
    this.cbManagers.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cbManagers_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.cbJobs.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cbJobs_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.cbEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged);
  }
  private void EnableComboEvents() {
    this.cbManagers.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbManagers_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.cbJobs.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbJobs_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.cbEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged);
  }


  // you will need to adjust the code below to your requirements
  private void SetDataTables() {
    employeesDT = Utilities.GetEmployeesDataTable(); // <-- table of employees
    evaluationsDT = Utilities.GetEvaluationsDT();    // <-- table of evaluations
    managersCBDT = Utilities.GetManagersDT();        // <-- table of managers (subset of employees)
    jobsCBDT = Utilities.GetJobsDT();                // <-- table of job types
  }

  private void SetEvaluationsDGVColumns() {
    dgvEvaluations.RowHeadersWidth = 20;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns["ID"].Width = 40;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns["Employee Evaluated"].Width = 140;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns["Evaluating Manager"].Width = 160;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns["Start Date"].Width = 65;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns["End Date"].Width = 65;
    SetScoreColumn("Personal Score", 60);
    SetScoreColumn("Impact Score", 60);
    SetScoreColumn("Communication Score", 85);
    SetScoreColumn("Decision Making Score", 60);
    SetScoreColumn("Knowledge Skills Score", 70);
    SetScoreColumn("Career Development Score", 80);
    SetScoreColumn("Interpersonal Score", 80);
  }

  private void SetScoreColumn(string colName, int colWidth) {
    dgvEvaluations.Columns[colName].Width = colWidth;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns[colName].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    dgvEvaluations.Columns[colName].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
  }

  private void SetEmployeeDGVColumns() {
    dgvEmployees.Columns["ID"].Width = 40;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["ID"].ReadOnly = true;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["Manager"].Width = 60;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["First Name"].Width = 80;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["Last Name"].Width = 150;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["Full Name"].Width = 150;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["Full Name"].ReadOnly = true;
    dgvEmployees.Columns["Job Title"].Width = 120;
  }


  private void SetEmployeeComboBox() {
    DataRow dr = employeesCBDT.NewRow();
    employeesCBDT.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    cbEmployees.DataSource = employeesCBDT;
    cbEmployees.DisplayMember = "Full Name";
    cbEmployees.SelectedIndex = -1;
  }
  private void SetManagerComboBox() {
    DataRow dr = managersCBDT.NewRow();
    managersCBDT.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    cbManagers.DataSource = managersCBDT;
    cbManagers.DisplayMember = "Full Name";
    cbManagers.SelectedIndex = -1;
  }
  private void SetJobsComboBox() {
    DataRow dr = jobsCBDT.NewRow();
    jobsCBDT.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    cbJobs.DataSource = jobsCBDT;
    cbJobs.DisplayMember = "Job Title";
    cbJobs.SelectedIndex = -1;
  }

  private void dgvEvaluations_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 5 && e.ColumnIndex < 13) {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for score!");
    } else {
      if (e.ColumnIndex > 3 && e.ColumnIndex < 6) {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid intput for date!");
      }
    }
    dgvEvaluations.CancelEdit();
  }

  private void cbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    evaluationsDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = GetFilterString();
  }

  private void cbManagers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    evaluationsDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = GetFilterString();
  }

  private void cbJobs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    evaluationsDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = GetFilterString();
  }

  private string GetFilterString() {
    string targetManager = cbManagers.Text.Trim();
    string targetJob = cbJobs.Text.Trim();
    string targetEmployee = cbEmployees.Text.Trim();

    if (targetManager != "") {
      if (targetEmployee != "") {
        if (targetJob != "") {
          return string.Format("[Evaluating Manager] = '{0}' AND [Employee Evaluated] = '{1}' AND [Job Title] = '{2}'", targetManager, targetEmployee, targetJob);
        } else {
          return string.Format("[Evaluating Manager] = '{0}' AND [Employee Evaluated] = '{1}'", targetManager, targetEmployee);
        }
      } else {
        if (targetJob != "") {
          return string.Format("[Evaluating Manager] = '{0}' AND [Job Title] = '{1}'", targetManager, targetJob);
        } else {
          return string.Format("[Evaluating Manager] = '{0}'", targetManager);
        }
      }
    } else {
      // manager is blank
      if (targetEmployee != "") {
        if (targetJob != "") {
          return string.Format("[Employee Evaluated] = '{0}' AND [Job Title] = '{1}'", targetEmployee, targetJob);
        } else {
          return string.Format("[Employee Evaluated] = '{0}'", targetEmployee);
        }
      } else {
        if (targetJob != "") {
          return string.Format("[Job Title] = '{0}'", targetJob);
        } else {
          return "";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void btManagers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    employeesDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Manager = '{0}'", "True");
    labelEmployeeList.Text = "Managers Only";
  }

  private void btAllEmployees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    employeesDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
    labelEmployeeList.Text = "All Employees";
  }

  private void btSaveEmployees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Utilities.WriteEmployessToFile(employeesDT);    // <-- update your database
  }

  private void btSaveEvals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Utilities.WriteEvaluationsToFile(evaluationsDT);    // <-- update your database
  }

  private void btClearEvalFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    cbManagers.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cbJobs.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cbEmployees.SelectedIndex = -1;
    evaluationsDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
  }


  // Code to make a combo box column in the datagridView
  ////-------------------------------------------
  //public static DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GetEmployeeComboBoxColumn(DataTable employeeDT) {
  //  return GetComboBoxColumn(employeeDT, "Full Name", "Employee Evaluated");
  //}
  ////-------------------------------------------
  //public static DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GetManagerComboBoxColumn(DataTable managerDT) {
  //  return GetComboBoxColumn(managerDT, "Full Name", "Evaluating Manager");
  //}
  ////-------------------------------------------
  //public static DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GetComboBoxColumn(DataTable comboDT, string displayMember, string headerText) {
  //  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  //  comboCol.DataPropertyName = headerText;
  //  comboCol.HeaderText = headerText;
  //  DataTable comboData = comboDT.Copy();
  //  DataRow dr = comboData.NewRow();
  //  comboData.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
  //  comboCol.DataSource = comboData;
  //  comboCol.DisplayMember = displayMember;
  //  comboCol.ValueMember = displayMember;
  //  comboCol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  //  return comboCol;
  //}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi again, first of all I'd like to express my gratitude for your comprehensive answer. I need some more time to check and learn all codes, but I think something important is missing here. As I mentioned before, cause we have a lot of Criteria and they are different for every job, putting all those criteria as fields in form is some how impossible. I can send you more necessary information via E-mail if possible.

Comment: If there are different criteria for each job, then you will have to make a `DataTable` for each job type. In addition, since the criteria are different for each job type, I would highly recommend you make classes for these different job types each with their own criteria. I am unsure what necessary information you could send via email that could not be posted here. If there is more information that is “necessary” then you should post this “necessary” information in your original question. Why would leave this “necessary” information out?

Answer (score 0):

With greatest thanks to dear JohnG for his complete guide and answer,here is what I finally did to show the data based on previous descriptions. I'll share my solution for inserting data ASAP.

```
namespace Scoring_Form
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = db.Jobs.ToList();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "JobTitle";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "JobId";
    }

    public DataTable subcrt(int JobId)
    {
        var row = from crt in db.SubCrts
                  join job in db.Jobs
                  on crt.JobId equals job.JobId
                  where job.JobId == JobId
                  select crt;

        MessageBox.Show(row.Count().ToString());
        return (DataTable)row;

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var querySubCrts = from crt in db.SubCrts
                           where crt.JobId == (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue
                           select crt;
        //--------- Add Personal Name  in Header
        var queryPersonal = from rwPr in db.Prs
                            select rwPr;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = queryPersonal.Count() + 1;
        int j = 0;
        foreach (var rwPrs in queryPersonal)
        {
            j++;
            dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText = rwPrs.FName + " " + rwPrs.LName;

            dataGridView1.RowCount = querySubCrts.Count() + 1;
            int i = -1;

            foreach (var crt in querySubCrts)
            {
                i++;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = crt.Title;
                //-------------
                var queryScoring = from rwScoring in db.Scorings
                                   where (rwScoring.SubCId == crt.SubCId) && (rwScoring.PrsId == rwPrs.PrsId)
                                   select rwScoring;

                foreach (var rwScoring in queryScoring)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = rwScoring.Score;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```